# Relationship between @@language global variable and default language setting in SQL Server instance

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

There is this default language setting at instance level in SQL Server which can be configured as below:

```
EXEC sp_configure 'default language', 23 ;  
GO  
RECONFIGURE ;  
GO
```

It changes the value of default language setting to `British English`.

But when I run below query in SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) it gives the output - `us_english`:

```
SELECT @@language
```

I'm confused between the instance level setting and the global variable. Can anyone help me understand the difference/relationship between the two?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per the [manual](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-the-default-language-server-configuration-option), `default language` only governs the language for newly created logins. Existing logins already have a language associated with them (`us_english`, in your case). To change *that*, use [`ALTER LOGIN ... WITH DEFAULT_LANGUAGE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-login-transact-sql).

`@@LANGUAGE` is the current language of the session. The default is taken from the login, but it can be changed within the session with [`SET LANGUAGE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/t-sql/statements/set-language-transact-sql), so it's not redundant with any settings.

Comment: What is @@language global variable then?

Comment: Got it. So `default language` setting is available at three hierarchical levels namely instance, login and session. Their default values have a sort of inheritance hierarchy `SQL Server Instance` -> `login` (when newly created) -> `Session` (when newly created). Thanks for the complete information.